# Method returning IEnumerable<T> should ToList() or not

Tags: c#, iterator

I can't decide whether my method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` should itself be lazy or whether it should build a list and return that. I often opt for the latter so I can be sure the enumeration of each value isn't performed multiple times.
For example:

```
public IEnumerable<UserProfile> GetUsers()
{
    var allDepartments = GetAllDepartments(active: true); // Returns IEnumerable<Department>
    var allUsers = GetAllUserDepartments(active: true); // Returns IEnumerable<User>
    var users
        = allDepartments
            .Join(allUsers, x => x.Department, y => y.Department, (x, y) => y, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(x => GetUserProfile(x))
            .ToList(); // Is this recommended or not

    return users;
}
```

The key part is each enumeration is doing something (`GetUserProfile`) non trivial, it might be expensive, it might not, but what's the recommendation for a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`? Should it care about whether the caller might enumerate it several times or not?

Assume only `IEnumerable<T>` functionality is required by the caller and my question can be reworded into:

How do I signify to the caller that each enumeration may be expensive?

How expensive it is, may change their implementation decisions. If they enumerate the whole lot several times, then a `ToList()` makes sense to them to perform. If they don't enumerate the whole lot, then a `ToList()` would be a waste for me (or the caller) to perform.

Comment: What would you expect if you look at the return type? Personally if I see IEnumerable I expect a lazy evaluated collection. If you call ToList() just return an IList or ICollection. Don't try to handle too much in a method. Just make it clear.

Comment: @dusky this makes sense, but remember that `IList` and `ICollection` are both mutable contracts. `IEnumerable` has the dual purpose of having lazy-evaluation semantics but also being a immutable structure to users.

Comment: @DanPantry .net 4.5 [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements IReadOnlyList and IReadOnlyCollection. But if you want a proper readonly collection return a proper immutable list.

Comment: @dusky Thanks, I think possibly IReadOnlyList is what I should return in my eager methods (that call ToList()). I try and avoid IList because ultimately I felt uncomfortable with the result being modified afterwards. IEnumerable for the lazy methods makes perfect sense.

Comment: depends on the what the criteria for "good" are.  See also immutable list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: @philsoady Bcl.Immutable collections are very slow. [AsReadOnly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is usually ok if you don't leak the underlying list.

Comment: "I often opt for the latter so I can be sure the enumeration of each value isn't performed multiple times" - If your caller wants to filter the results, and if you return using ToList(), then you're guaranteeing two iterations. If you didn't use ToList(), and let the caller just filter the IEnumerable<T>, it'd be just one enumeration.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Does code that calls the method always expect `List` functionality (access by index, etc.)? Return a `List`. Does code that calls the method only expect to iterate over it? Return an `IEnumerable`.

You shouldn't care about what the caller does with it, because the return type clearly states what the returned value is capable of doing. *Any* caller that gets an `IEnumerable` result knows that if they want indexed access of the result, they will have to convert to a `List`, because `IEnumerable` simple isn't capable of it until it's been enumerated and put into an indexed structure. Don't assume that the callers are stupid, otherwise you end up taking functionality *away* from them. For example, by returning a `List`, you've taken away the ability to stream results which can have its own performance benefits. Your implementation may change, but the caller can always turn an `IEnumerable` into a `List` if they need to.

Now that you've decided what the return type should be, you have to decide what the *implementation* should use. Deferred execution has benefits, but can also be confusing. Take this example:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetRecordIds()
{
    return dbContext.Records.Select(r => r.Id);
}

IEnumerable<int> currentRecordIds = GetRecordIds();

dbContext.Add(new Record { Id = 7 });

// Includes "7", despite GetRecordIds() being called before the Add():
currentRecordIds.Dump();
```

This can be "remedied" by `GetRecordIds` calling `ToList` before returning. The "correct" use here simply depends on what is expected of the class ("live" results, or time of call results).

Again, don't assume the caller is stupid, and don't take away functionality from the caller by making assumptions about how it will be used. Remember, the interface *tells you* what is expected to be returned. `IEnumerable` *only* means you are getting something that can be iterated over (potentially streaming results and making use of deferred execution), and `List` *only* means you're getting an in-memory collection that can be added to, removed from, accessed by index, etc.

Edit - To address your "Update 1":

If you are really concerned, you might add some information into the documentation, but I don't think it's necessary. The `IEnumerable` interface doesn't claim to make any promises about performance on repeat enumeration (or even each iteration for that matter), so it's on the caller to handle it intelligently.

Comment: Your point of view is very interesting. I'm just bothered by the defered execution of the enumerable.. But still, it's a great answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm a bit confused, you're asking what the code that calls it does then saying I shouldn't care about what the caller does.

Comment: The first lines mean to say: does the API you're trying to expose to callers wish to imply that the results are useful as an indexed set that can be modified or not?

Comment: I am also not saying "don't care about what the caller does". I am saying "don't assume you know better than the caller by forcing them to use `List` (unless the intended use of the method is *always* need indexed access, etc.).

Comment: @Ocelot20 OK, I think my Update 1 clarifies what I'm trying to achieve. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Agree with this. IMO, any code that enumerates over the same IEnumerable multiple times is potentially problematic, so the burden is on the consumer to make sure they're not doing something silly. If they are, it's on them, and is not really indicative of a problem with the method's implementation. Heck, ReSharper would put a blue squiggly under any code that enumerated your IEnumerable return value twice.

Comment: @moarboilerplate Good point and good tip, I don't currently have a license for ReSharper, one day I hope. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 15):

I think the real question here is **can the return value be lazily evaluated**? This is essentially what this comes down to.

`IEnumerable` is lazily evaluated in that any operations you apply to it (through Linq, or any sensible author) will be deferred until the last possible moment i.e, until you try and observe the `IEnumerable` by iterating or by using a fold (`First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`). This is a **good thing** in most cases because it means you can completely avoid doing any work until you need to - which sometimes means that a potentially expensive operation never actually occurs. Awesome!

However, this doesn't work so well when it comes to sequences that are retrieved from some unmanaged resource. Your example of this is perfect - a database. An `IEnumerable` backed by a database should *not* be lazily evaluated, as the connection it was bound to can potentially be closed by the time it is enumerated.

The exception to this is if you can find some way of binding the lifecycle of a connection to an `IEnumerable` - in other words, can you teach the `IEnumerable` how to instantiate a connection/other resource, use it, and then dispose it. In some applications this solution might not be viable due to the performance impact, and you might feel uneasy about the loss of control here (this is where IoC comes in handy).

There is a framework called Rx (**R**eactive E**x**tensions) for .NET that actually has a feature in this built in called `Observable.Using()`. An observable is a class that can be **observed**, and is lazily evaluated - much like `IEnumerable`. In fact, `IObservable` implements `IEnumerable`. By using `Observable.Using()`, you can bind the creation of an object through a factory method to the lifetime of an `IObservable`. When the `IObservable` is first observed, the resource is created. When the `IObservable` is finished being observed, the resource is `Dispose()`d. Neat and tidy.

Back to the crux of your question, though; in this case, I would say, yes, `ToList()` the `IEnumerable` before returning the control to the caller; you **will** run into concurrency issues otherwise, and you have no guarantee that the connection will still be alive when you return control to the caller. But make sure to return an `IEnumerable` still - `IEnumerable` has a dual purpose in that it is very good at representing a read-only collection.

Comment: "you *will* run into concurrency issues" is a bit harsh. There are plenty of perfectly acceptable reasons to return a lazily evaluated IEnumerable from a db. It all comes down to what that individual class claims to be responsible for. Also, "you have no guarantee the connection will be alive" is a concern of the class returning the `IEnumerable`, not the caller.

Comment: I am assuming OP is using EntityFramework.
If he is, then he will run into concurrency issues if he does not `ToList()` the enumerable, and I am only saying that out of pain born from doing exactly the opposite. I did point out though that if you can bind the lifetime of the resource to the IEnumerable that this is circumvented.

Comment: To be clear, it was not meant to be harsh. But I would say that having a lazily evaluated structure coming straight from the DB layer and leaving the DB layer is likely to be a *bad thing* if it talks directly to the database connection. As I mentioned, certainly in Ef, you will run into a lot of problems by doing this.

Comment: "harsh" was a poor choice of words on my part. I guess I meant "overly generalized statement". Whether or not he'll run into concurrency issues highly depends on what he's exposing/doing with the results. Like I mentioned before, there are plenty of acceptable reasons to return a lazily evaluated `IEnumerable` from a db, but without seeing more code we can't really say what problems he'll run into. It's certainly a potential problem worth mention though.

Comment: @DanPantry thanks for your answer, there is no DB, the Users and Departments are cached and the UserProfile may reside in cache, may reside in DB, may reside in table storage or disk or somewhere else. I've not used IObservable<T>, does it complicate the code compared with using the LINQ extension methods against an IEnumerable<T>. It does sound like one to look into. Do you have any ideas how it could be implemented?

Comment: I certainly prefer to "assume the caller is stupid" and return `IReadOnlyCollection` although you'll have to call `ToList()` when passing around other interfaces... so not perfect

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use `var` if it is to put a comment stating the return type, if it isn't clear without the comment, put the real type instead of `var`, it is more readable this way.

To answer you question, I think that yes you should call `ToList` before returning the enumeration mainly because your `IEnumerable<UserProfile>` could be an EF query and there's no way for the user of your class to know this, meaning the person could use this enumeration multiple times and launch tons of SQL queries without knowing it (until there would be performance problems and diagnostic would lead to that `IEnumerable` launching queries).

The performance cost of using `ToList` is the same as using `new List<>([your enumerable])` constructor, which is an O(n) operation since you need to copy the whole array. If you have a very big enumerable that you don't want to copy all the time, maybe you should consider adding a parameter to your method that would let you decide if you execute the `IEnumerable` or not this way :

```
public IEnumerable<UserProfile> GetUsers(bool deferExecution)
{
    IEnumerable<Department> allDepartments = GetAllDepartments(active: true);
    IEnumerable<User> allUsers = GetAllUserDepartments(active: true);
    IEnumerable<UserProfile> users
        = allDepartments
            .Join(allUsers, x => x.Department, y => y.Department, (x, y) => y, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(x => GetUserProfile(x));

    if(!deferExecution) 
    {
        users = users.ToList();
    }

    return users;
}
```

Though honestly, I've never tried it with the boolean in real life so I can't tell if it is a really good idea, but I feel it wouldn't be bad!

If you want more info about the performance cost of `ToList`, check this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516462/is-there-a-performance-impact-when-calling-tolist)

Comment: Interesting idea with the `deferExecution` argument.

Comment: That is not how `IEnumerable` works. Returning an `IQueryable` as an `IEnumerable` or `List` will be no different WRT how many times the query is executed. The number of times the method is called, as well as whether or not the consumer iterates over the result would be the determining factor.

Comment: What does WRT means?

Comment: "With Regards To" I assume

Comment: Yes, I did mean "with regards to".

Comment: @TopinFrassi Agreed about the var comments, my example has comments I added later, I wouldn't normally have them there ;) Thanks for the defer argument idea, it at least gives the caller a choice, if I made it a default parameter then it's up to them to make it lazy or eager.